# Access staticContext through hook in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, server-side-rendering

I want to create a generic "not-found" component that sets the statusCode to 404 if the `StaticRouter` is used. I know that I can do this:

```js
<Route
  render={(routeComponentProps) => <NotFound {...routeComponentProps} />}
/>
```

Or use a child function as the doc describes, but as my app is growing in complexity I'd like to simplify it down to the way I specify all my other routes in order to avoid having to remember to pass props to the NotFound component. Something like this:

```js
<Route>
  <NotFound />
</Route>
```

This means I'd like to access `staticContext` inside `<NotFound/>` using a hook (preferrably), but unfortunately that does not seem possible at this time as the `useRouteMatch` hook does not return `staticContext`.

My current workaround is to grab `__RouterContext` from inside `react-router` and pass it to a `useContext` hook, but this seems hacky and is probably not supported. However it does work fine both server-side and client side (using the normal `BrowserRouter`)

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import { __RouterContext } from "react-router"

export const NotFound: React.FC = () => {
    const { staticContext } = useContext(__RouterContext)
    if (staticContext) {
        staticContext.statusCode = 404
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <h3>404: Not found</h3>
        </div>
    )
}

export default NotFound
```

Is there a hook I can use or perhaps plans to start supporting this within the `useRouteMatch` hook?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that you can access staticContext inside  using a documented hook. If an undocumented hook existed it would not be a better workaround than your current `__RouterContext` trick (which I find quite elegant already).

You could do something though, if you relax your "hook" requirement. Which is probably OK: hooks are great to reuse logic, but don't need to be usedto solve every problem.

You can access the `staticContext` inside your `<NotFound />` without any prop: you just need to add a newcatch-all `<Route />` [inside](https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/server-rendering/404-401-or-any-other-status).

```
export const NotFound: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <Route
      render={({ staticContext }) => {
        if (staticContext) {
          staticContext.statusCode = 404
        }

        return (
          <div>
            <h3>404: Not found</h3>
          </div>
        )
      }}
    >
  )
}

...

<Route>
  <NotFound />
</Route>
```

Comment: Even though it is not using hooks I think this is preferable as it avoids utilizing undocumented (and potentially unsupported) code.